# Configuring hibernate to retrieve a collection without persisting it

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Database:

I have a three-way join table called `Users_Accounts_Roles`.

```
+--------------+------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field        | Type       | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+--------------+------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id           | bigint(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| user_id      | bigint(20) | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                |
| account_id   | bigint(20) | NO   |     | 0                 |                |
| role_id      | bigint(20) | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
+--------------+------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

Users can belong to multiple accounts and can have multiple roles for each of those accounts.

I also have a `User` table

```
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default             | Extra                       |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
| id             | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment              |
| email          | varchar(255) | NO   | UNI | NULL                |                             |
| firstName      | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL                |                             |
| lastName       | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL                |                             |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
```

An `Account` table

```
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default             | Extra                       |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
| id           | bigint(20)  | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment              |
| name         | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL                |                             |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
```

And a `Role` table

```
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id           | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| name         | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| description  | text         | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

Objects (sparsely):

```
@Embeddable
AccountRole {
  ...

  @Parent
  User getUser() {
    return user;
  }

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "account_id")
  Account getAccount() {
    return account;
  }

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
  Role getRole() {
    return role;
  }

  ...
}

@Entity
User {
  ...

  @Transient
  Set<Account> getAccounts() {
    return accounts;
  }

  @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinTable(name = "Users_Accounts_Roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
  Set<AccountRole> getAccountRoles() {
    return accountRoles;
  }

  ...
}

@Entity
Account {
  ...

  @Transient
  Set<User> users;

  ...
}
```

I want `User.accounts` to be populated with the data in `Users_Accounts_Roles` when a `User` is fetched from the database, but I don't want changes to `User.accounts` to influence updates to `Users_Accounts_Roles` when a `User` is persisted. Similarly, I want `Account.users` to be populated with the data in `Users_Accounts_Roles` when an Account is fetched from the database, but I don't want changes to `Accounts.users` to influence updates to `Users_Accounts_Roles` when an `Account` is persisted. The only way the `Users_Accounts_Roles` table should change is if a `User` is persisted with an updated `accountRoles` field.

As is, the `User.accountRoles` mapping is working to my liking (both retrieving from and persisting to `Users_Accounts_Roles`), but I can't find a way for `User.accounts` and `Account.users` to be retrieved upon `User` and `Account` fetching, respectively, but not persisted when a `User` or `Account` is persisted, without using some ugly logic in the DAO layer. (They are currently marked as Transient since nothing else I tried worked). Does Hibernate/JPA support what I'm trying to do?

-----EDIT-----

I suspect my solution may involve using `@OneToMany(mappedBy="...")` on `User.accounts` and `Account.users` as done in [this tutorial](http://java-aap.blogspot.com/2006/04/hibernate-annotations-composite.html). However, I can't figure out how to annotate the fields in `AccountRole` and the `User.accountRoles` field to make it so that changes to the latter are still persisted.

Answer (score 0):

You could try mapping `user.accounts` with a `@ManyToMany`, using `@JoinTable(name ="Users_Accounts_Roles", joinColumns=...)`. By default `@*ToMany` does not cascade anything so you don't risk adding/removing entries by mistake. However, modifying the `Account`'s themselves will be persisted, but this is only due to the fact that they are managed entities. Anyway, those `Account` objects will be the same as those linked through the `user.accountRoles` collections so I guess this should not be an issue.

Take care to the performances of such a solution since it could lead to perform a lot of queries (e.g. one additional query for each user for fetching his accounts).

Alternatively you could simply implement a (read-only) `Collection<Account>` wrapper that would delegate all its calls to the `user.accountRoles` collection (just calling `getAccount()` on the `AccountRole` objects it returns). This way you could control every operation, and make sure that the relation is only fetched once.